# How can I extract data from php and mysql for column and spline chart in highchart

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

I  try to make a combo chart of column with spline highchart. I want this type of chart from highcharts [link] http://jsfiddle.net/sunman/dwyNz/8/. But here is my problem is I want to show my dynamic data both spline and column chart which comes from data.php using json  for data retrieve. But my graph will not show properly like this [link] http://jsfiddle.net/sunman/dwyNz/8/ .

I want this type of graph through my code.in spline line I want to show 'bsp values' from query1 and in column chart I want to facility rating. Here is my code where I extract data through json:-

*data.php*

```
   $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT projects_detail.Project_name,superfac_rating.faci_total 
 FROM projects_detail LEFT OUTER JOIN superfac_rating 
 ON projects_detail.project_id= superfac_rating.project_id ");

   $category = array();
    $category['name'] = 'Project';


  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
   $category['data'][] = $row1['Project_name'];
  $series1['data'][] = $row1['faci_total'];
 }

    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT projects_detail.Project_name,superfac_rating.faci_total 
    FROM projects_detail LEFT OUTER JOIN superfac_rating 
   ON projects_detail.project_id= superfac_rating.project_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN cost ON gsuperfac_rating.project_id=cost.project_id  ");

  $series1 = array();
  $series1['name'] = 'Project Name';
  $series2 = array();
  $series2['name'] = 'BSP VALUES';

  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
   $series1['data'][] = $row2['faci_total'];
    $series2['data'][] = $row2['bsp'];
     }
    $result = array();
         array_push($result,$category);
        array_push($result,$series1);
        array_push($result,$series1);
         array_push($result,$series2);

        print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Here I am design for graph:

```
       $(function () {
        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
       $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Project facility Rating'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'testing'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: []
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
              //  format: '{value} Rs.',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Bsp Cost',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Facility Rating',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                //format: '{value} out of 100',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme &&    Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: json
    });
      });
       });
        });
```

so tell me why my json code not create a graph ..

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Comment: @Raptor i have no idea about syntax of MySQLi or PDO .so can you please suggest how can write code through this with my example.

Comment: Both jsfiddle links are the same. Also, show your json.

Comment: How your json looks like ?

Comment: @jdo please see this  [link] http://jsfiddle.net/sunman/dwyNz/10/  and my data.php code written on above

Comment: @sunman Read the manual !

Comment: @SebastianBochan my graph shows four straighlines

Comment: Provide your json, otherwise no one can help you. For the ease of use, post a link to your false rendered graph.

Comment: @jdo .sorry actually i dont know in which section i will add my json code of Jsfiddle.net.So added my json code on above where i write my question (so please see data.php)tell me how can i write my code otherwise u will show me a example where i can write json code

Comment: You might guess, that none of us can access your database, so we cannot and will not rebuild what your data.php's output will look like. The information you're missing to provide is the return value of your data.php. Your js function request this value and stores it in a variable called `json`. Then you use this var to fill the `series` in the highchart. What everybody here is asking for: What is inside `json`?

Comment: @jdo r u there?please suggest me

Comment: Just call your data.php. It should print the json to the screen.

Comment: @jdo please see this [link] http://jsfiddle.net/sunman/dwyNz/11/   here i have already call the json function.and i added my data.php file in css section.please check quickly.

Comment: I don't know how I can be any clearer on what data I want to get from you. Seems to be a language barrier ... Sorry, can't help.